# Dynamically loading controller with angularjs and requirejs

Tags: angularjs, requirejs

I am trying to integrate angularjs app with requirejs. I want to preload templates and controllers on-demand. In my example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/vIps7t92OFzA5RXoTjvI?p=preview

I init controller SocialController inside the app.js and I need to load dynamically StreamController inside the SocialController. Unfortunately I am getting an exception, see browser console.

> Argument 'StreamController' is not a function, got undefined

If I remove from SocialController

```
angular.module('sampleTest').controller('StreamController', StreamController);
```

and add it to app.js, it works but in this case requirejs will preload it right at the beginning and not when I need, inside the SocialController on demand.

Comment: Lazy loading Angular code is tricky (it shouldn't be IMO). Take a look at my take on this [angular-require-lazy](https://github.com/nikospara/angular-require-lazy) - there are also others around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an answer. Looks like angular does not allow instantiating any new services or controllers later on, after the app startup. So the code below I had to add to app.js files at the bottom, after all the controller and services are init. This is a hack but fixes the problem for lazy loading with requirejs.

See my link to plunkr with the fix. Now there are no exception and StreamController is lazy loaded and init after the startup.

```
sampleApp.config(
            function (
                $controllerProvider,
                $compileProvider,
                $filterProvider,
                $provide
            ) {
                sampleApp.controller = $controllerProvider.register;
                sampleApp.directive = $compileProvider.directive;
                sampleApp.filter = $filterProvider.register;
                sampleApp.factory = $provide.factory;
                sampleApp.service = $provide.service;
            }
        );
```